# What does A=B (B [:,])*! mean in Cincom Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I'm new to Smalltalk and now using Antlr to parse Cincom Smalltalk code.  There is only a very short piece of code within `<body ...>` and `</body>`, but I couldn't parse it and couldn't find the related rules.  Could anyone explain to me what this code means?

```
mbs = mbGroup (mbGroup [:,])*!
```

If you could further share the related parsing rule, that would be the best.

Comment: I removed the ANTLR tag because nowhere in the question was any ANTLR code/syntax. If you decide to ask a new question, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this supposed to be a piece of Smalltalk code or something else? Looks more like a grammar rule expression to me, but then I'm missing the context.

Comment: In Smalltalk-80 and descendant dialects (including Cincom Smalltalk), it is possible to define a specific Parser at class level: that means that it is technically possible that the methods of a class (and its subclasses) abide to a non-Smalltalk grammar. Could it be the case here? Does any class define a class-side method named #parserClass?

Comment: If you use ANTLR to parse the method body, it's certainly not able to decipher the alternate parserClass and its corresponding grammar rules. That could explain. Smalltalk is a very dynamic language, even w.r.t. to its syntax!

Comment: @aka.nice yeah it's very possible!  Now I feel that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not syntactically legal Smalltalk code, therefore the question what its semantics are is non-sensical. It has no meaning in Smalltalk because it is not Smalltalk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Would it be the problem of Smalltalk's version?  The code I'm trying to deal with is of Cincom.  I'm new to Smalltalk so I'm not sure how different the version would cause.  Maybe I should make this clearer in my question.

Comment: Please note that Aaron is not saying that his code is Smalltalk. It's a question about Antlr trying to _parse_ the Smalltalk language. So please don't go calling the question non-sensical.

Comment: Having just looked at the question's edits, I can see that the question title went from saying "what does it mean in Smalltalk" to "what does it mean in Antlr" and back to "what does it mean in Cincom Smalltalk". Reverting my downvote to this answer given the context (but it's locked until answer is edited...), and have updated the question to clarify its intent.

Comment: Hi Amos, I'm thankful for your opinion and sorry for the confusion.  I'm actually firstly asking about the meaning in Smalltalk.  If someone can further explain how Antlr can parse it, that would be the best.  Someone just added "in Antlr" to the title, but that's not what I mean (so I modified it back).  This code really appears in Smalltalk.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying... in that case, Joerg's answer is correct (sorry Joerg, I can't take back the downvote until the post is edited). It doesn't make sense in a Smalltalk context, including Cincom's version.

Comment: Except if ever the class side defines an alternate #parserClass. In which case, the syntax is non Smalltalk, but the question is still sensical. It's just that it lacks some information that we could eventually help to find.